# I'm sure a Facebook group accept join requests as page, but I cannot do that. What can I do?

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-groups, facebook-account

Requesting to join a Facebook group will prompt a box to select whether you want to join as your profile or as a page. But sometimes there seems to be a bug making that panel not showing. I try turning off adblock, but it still doesn't work. So far I have to blindly click the button and see if the box shows up or not. If not, then I have to cancel the request and refresh the page again. That's inefficient.

What are the efficient ways to know that I don't have to refresh anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When hovering the button there will be a tooltip like this:

[image]

So you just need to refresh the site until this shows up. It does seem that only the original creator can request to join.